# dotTrace cant create deploy folder on Windows Azure Web Sites (WAWS)

Tags: azure, jetbrains-ide, dottrace

I get the error message 'Can't create deploy folder.' when I try to profile a remote websites on WAWS.

Actions taken:

- Downloaded and installed the dotTrace Profiler 5.5 from the JetBrains website
- Downloaded the dotTrace.Performance.Remote version 5.5.0 from Nuget
- Published the website to WAWS via Visual Studio 2013
- Started the dotTrace application as Administrator
- Connected to the remote _https://subdomain.azurwebsites.net/AgentService.asmx. See image: http://1drv.ms/1nF5Cyh
- Selected the w3wp process and pressed Run
- Got the error message 'Can't create deploy folder'. See image: http://1drv.ms/U5h35A

I'm running dotTrace in trial mode at the moment. Swift help is much appreciated.

Orhan

Comment: AFAIK Windows Azure does not allow to do thing like that. But i would conntact with support on Your place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported yet (June 2014), work is being done to get support ready.

Comment: I'm running into the same. Is there another way to profile a Azure Websites site? I published WCF services that use WIF/token authentication and although it works, it's extremely slow on Azure websites. There run fine in an IaaS setup.